# How to recreate this zig-zag / andean pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I have tried a few different attempts on this pattern. I was wondering if someone could show me how to recreate this Jordan 12 pattern (black and yellow) on the sole of the shoe:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have made so far? Will make it easier to come up with suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, I do something like this [programatically using *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24155/187), but let me give you a fast way for Photoshop.

**1.** Create a small empty image, say 40x40 pixel

**2.** In the first column, you make every 5 pixel black, so that you end up with something like this:

> [image]

**3.** Now you press the button for the *selection tool* a bit longer and you choose the tool *one column selection*. Now, the approach is very easy: Select your first column and press `V` to select the move tool. Now, you hold `Alt` and press `Right Arrow`, release `Alt` and press down arrow. This creates your correct second column. Do this another 4 times downwards, then start upwards and you get

> [image]

**4.** Repeat this for another 30 seconds and you are done

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to create a seamless pattern that will reproduce the motive. You image is basically a big zig-zag with smaller zig-zags on the borders (a very popular motive in the south-american Andean region).

Here's a **very quick and dirty** example, you can start with a normal zig-zag:

[image]

And then work your way to the zig-zag blocks for the borders:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Do not try to use my images because I drew them in a hurry and will not fit properly :) But I hope you get the idea!